# I am getting an error when using await as part of a sleep function

Tags: javascript

I'm setting up my first discord bot and when i run "node bot.js" it comes up with an error where i have tried to implement an await sleep(time) system. If there's a better way of doing it that would be good or a fix to the current problem.

Previously had a different system in place to try and delay the system but it didn't work either so i switched to this but couldn't find where the cause of the error.

```
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}  //function relating to problematic line

bot.on('message', function (user, userID, channelID, message, evt) {
    if (message.substring(0, 1) == '!') {
        var args = message.substring(1).split(' ');
        var cmd = args[0];

    args = args.splice(1);
        switch(cmd) {
            case 'repeat':
        while (x == 1){
            bot.sendMessage({
                to: channelID,
                message: 'repeated message'
            await sleep(10000); //line with problem
            }
                });
            break;
         }
     }
});
```

This error occurs:

```
await sleep(86400000);
^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
    at new Script (vm.js:80:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:274:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:326:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:664:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
```

Comment: Ignore code format on error section, stack had a hissy fit

Comment: You can only use `await` in async functions. Also the line `await sleep(10000);` seems to be in the middle of an object literal. Is that supposed to be outside the `}`?

Comment: `bot.on('message', async function (user, userID, channelID, message, evt) {`
add the word async at the start of your function. function needs to be declared as async in order to use await within

Answer (score 0):

Mark your `bot` callback as `async`.

Move your `await` call outside of your `sendMessage` object declaration.

Fix your curly brace nesting.

```
bot.on('message', async function (user, userID, channelID, message, evt) {
    if (message.substring(0, 1) == '!') {
        var args = message.substring(1).split(' ');
        var cmd = args[0];

    args = args.splice(1);
        switch(cmd) {
            case 'repeat':
        while (x == 1){
            bot.sendMessage({
                to: channelID,
                message: 'repeated message'
                });
            await sleep(10000); //line with problem
        } //while
        break;
        } // switch
     } // if
});
```

Comment: ah ok woops. ty